# Ran "sudo-apt install dist-upgrade" taking very long time

Tags: update

started sudo-apt install dist-upgrade. Last line showing is,
"Get:203 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie/main libgles.resa arrf 13.0.0-i+rpil [52.4 kb]. This has been counting up for hours now. Is there something wrong or is there a number it counts up too. Tanks for any help.
BTW, this is on a Raspberry Pi 2.

Answer (score 1):

It basically says it is downloading package 203 of the amount of packages it needs to download. It also gives a percentage of progress. When you've started the update is has shown you the number of packages to download (updates or new) and the number of packages to remove (if any). Eventually it will complete the update procedure unless it has lost the internet connection.

**Do not interrupt the update procedure unless you have no other choice or you may corrupt your OS.**

Answer (score 0):

There was a major version update to the OS at the start of July, You will be replacing a lot of the OS. You should see the progress in the terminal window.

You should have made sure you ran update and upgrade prior to starting the distro upgrade.

How long it will take will depend upon you internet connection and how busy the repository server is processing updates and upgrades.